# Why am I getting a non-numeric vector from optimizing a function?

Tags: r, optimization, vector, alphanumeric

I define the output vector as numeric:

```
`surv <- vector("numeric", 38)`
```

The input for the function is Np, a numeric vector, and a variable S to be optimized.

I then run the following code:

```
'dif <- function(S){
(Np[x] - (Np[x-1]*S + Np[x-4]*0.7*S^4))^2
   }
surv[x] <- optimize(dif, c(0, 1), maximum = FALSE, tol = 0.1)
}'
```

The code runs successfully and I can plot surv and apply ksmooth to it without a problem, but when I try to do further computations with the vector surv, I get the following message:

"Error in ....... : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

I have tried "unlist(surv)" and "as.numeric(surv)" but still encounter the same problem.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct this so that surv is a numeric vector that I can use in further computations? Thanks

Comment: What is this language? It looks like R. Please add the right tag for that. If you do not, then people that can answer this question might never see it (tags are watched by people interested in it on stack-overflow).

Comment: Thanks, Jerome. I've added the tag.

Comment: I have solved the problem. My error was in assuming that the output from 'optimize' was a single value i.e. the value that best fit the objective function. Having established that the output is a list consisting of the objective and the minimum, I can extract the elements I want  simply using xxx$minimum.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You can write this as an answer if you want so to make it more visible (for potential future users).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. My error was in a) not reading the R documentation on 'optimize' carefully and, as a result, b)assuming that the output from 'optimize' was a single value i.e. the minimum for the objective function. Having now established that the output is a list consisting of the objective and the minimum, I can extract the elements I want simply using xxx$minimum.

I am surprised, however, that despite this problem in my original code, saving the results of optimizing the defined function as elements of a vector (surv) did not generate an error and that a plot of 'surv' produced a plot of the minimums, which is what I had expected. Nevertheless, the key message for me is read the fine print!